# SQL Error when importing from a DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

I've connected my DB to a table.swing and the moment i try running the program an error occurs, i have no idea whats causing it, does anyone know what to do??

:

> [EL Info]: 2014-08-05
>   10:31:08.419--ServerSession(1167725985)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5 [EL Info]: connection:
>   2014-08-05
>   10:31:08.609--ServerSession(1167725985)--file:/C:/Users/Ghostk3/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BassonKochITPAT2014/build/classes/*ITAppPU
>   login successful [EL Warning]: 2014-08-05
>   10:31:08.667--UnitOfWork(1431000052)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'EMPLOYEE' is
>   either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join
>   specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or
>   appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is
>   a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'EMPLOYEE' is not a column in
>   the target table. Error Code: -1 Call: SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL,
>   EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME, STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES Query:
>   ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Employees sql="SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL,
>   EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME, STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES")
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'EMPLOYEE' is
>   either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join
>   specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or
>   appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is
>   a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'EMPLOYEE' is not a column in
>   the target table. Error Code: -1 Call: SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL,
>   EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME, STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES Query:
>   ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Employees sql="SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL,
>   EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME, STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES")     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
>     at bassonkochitpat2014.App2014.initComponents(App2014.java:38)  at
>   bassonkochitpat2014.App2014.(App2014.java:22)   at
>   bassonkochitpat2014.App2014$2.run(App2014.java:199)   at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services
>   - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'EMPLOYEE' is
>   either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join
>   specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or
>   appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is
>   a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'EMPLOYEE' is not a column in
>   the target table. Error Code: -1 Call: SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL,
>   EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME, STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES Query:
>   ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Employees sql="SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL,
>   EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME, STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES")     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1991)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2738)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2691)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:495)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1793)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1775)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1740)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
>     ... 18 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column
>   'EMPLOYEE' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears
>   within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join
>   specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY
>   list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'EMPLOYEE' is
>   not a column in the target table.     at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1556)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1505)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:619)
>     ... 38 more Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException:
>   Column 'EMPLOYEE' is either not in any table in the FROM list or
>   appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the
>   join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the
>   GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then
>   'EMPLOYEE' is not a column in the target table.   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput*(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 43 more BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

It says the column EMPLOYEE is not there for the table which you are trying to query as per this error:

> Column 'EMPLOYEE' is either not in any table in the FROM list or
>   appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the
>   join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the
>   GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement then
>   'EMPLOYEE' is not a column in the target table. Error Code: -1 Call:
>   SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL, EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME, STARTED
>   FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Employees
>   sql="SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL, EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME,
>   STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES")

Also the query is not correct - `SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL, EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME,STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES`

Try using : `SELECT ID, EMAIL, LASTNAME, NAME, STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES` if your column names are `ID, EMAIL, LASTNAME, NAME, STARTED`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the query is looking for a column "Employee" in your table. Since you want to have
'Employee ID' i suggest you try "Employee.ID" or just "ID", since you only have one table defined in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement looks fishy to me:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE ID, EMAIL, EMPLOYEE LASTNAME, EMPLOYEE NAME, STARTED FROM NBUSER.EMPLOYEES
```

SQL thinks EMPLOYEE is a column, which it does not find. Probably ID, LASTNAME, NAME are valid column names.

My suggestion is for you to find out the exact table definition and get to the root cause of why "EMPLOYEE" appears as a prefix in some columns. Is it your code or is it coming from some configuration file as part of the framework? Solving your issue is trivial. To make sure you don't face similar problems during development, always get to the root cause.